# BeautifulSoup python throwing errno22 error invalidmode ('r')

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write an image archiver of sorts in python that downloads images from a specific site, and I keep getting an ioerror errno22 invalid mode ('r') or filename error that appears on my beautifulsoup line

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(pahealUrl))

aTagList = soup.findall("a")

for randomTag in aTagList:
  if randomTag.find(text="Image Only"):
    imageList.append(randomTag) 

print randomTag
```

the url itself is valid, and I am not seeing what the problem is. any idea as to why its throwing the errno22 invalid mode /filename error?

Comment: You cannot just `open` URL like that. You need to access the page, for example with `urllib2`

Comment: so if I had the url of the page I wanted to parse, using BeautifulSoup and urllib2 what would I do? kind of new to python so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the html of a webpage, use the [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) library:

```
import urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen(myurl).read()
```

`open()` is not used to open web pages but for files. That's why you're getting a filename error.

Then you can `BeautifulSoup()` the HTML to get your soup.

Comment: this works great, just a couple quick questions. what is <a href='blahblah'>this data called?</a> and how would I check it once I have the links listed?

Comment: <a>'s normally associate with links. i.e, your <a> right there would link to the page blahblah but on the webpage it would display "this data called?".

To get the "this data called" you could first find all the <a>'s (using findAll()) and then `.text`